# Import large database from bacpac with SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, bacpac

I'm trying to import a large database to a Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (v13.0.2164.0) from a bacpac export with Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Management Studio.

To import I right click `Databases`, select `Tasks` and `Import Data-tier Application`.

The problem is that it always times out. I managed to do the import by truncating a large tables with unimportant data, but I have other databases to import where I can't delete as much, so I'm wondering how I can do such imports without getting a timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this cmd:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" /Action:Import
>   /SourceFile:"c:\DB.bacpac" /TargetConnectionString:"Data
>   Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True;"
>   /p:CommandTimeout="0"